# Switched to ASP.NET 3.5, DropDownList doesn't remember dynamically added items

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-3.5, viewstate

I have a site that uses a couple DropDownLists that are databound. I was also doing the traditional if (!IsPostBack) {list.Databind();} and relied on viewstate to keep the lists filled during a post back. I recently converted the site to ASP.NET 3.5 and noticed that the lists are empty during postback (as if ViewState is disabled). I didn't explicitly disable anything, and am wondering if anyone has seen a similar change or behavior in their viewstate dependent controls.

Thanks!

James

Comment: What type of datasource are you using for the lists?  How/where are the datasources defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have definitely seen similar problems (though mine were with visibility). Try to ensure that the ViewState is explicitly enabled on the whole control hierarchy down to the dropdown.

e.g.

```
‹asp:Page EnableViewState="True" ...›
     ...

     ‹asp:Panel EnableViewState="True"...›
         ...
         ‹asp:DropDownList EnableViewState="True" ...›
         ...
      ...
...
```

R.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I found the disabled viewstate in the master page (missed it somehow in my Edit-Find In Files search). Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This snippet pasted into the troublesome page is a quick way to see where viewstate is enabled/disabled.

```
<%
Control c = <YourMisbehavingControlNameHere>;

while ( c != null )
{
    Response.Write( c.GetType().Name + " = " + c.EnableViewState.ToString() + "<br/>" );

    c = c.Parent;
}

%>
```